# Logging function call output to file in GDB

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm trying to get GDB's output directed to file for further reference. I don't want to use `run > file`, because from what I noticed so far it executes it from begin till end. What I need is to be able to call some commands and all of this being recorded.
I've tried using `set logging on` which sort of work, but when I'm calling functions that are supposed to print to `stdout` it doesn't save thisinformation. What I mean:

```
set logging on
p myVar
$0 = 1
call myFunc()
This is output from myFunc
```

where myFunc() is

```
void myFunc() {
    cout<< "This is output from myFunc\n";
}
```

and in gdb.txt I can only see

```
$0 = 1
```

How can I also see output from call?

Comment: Redirect and save the output of gdb.

Comment: @KamilCuk how exactly? Keep in mind I'd like to interact with gdb at the same time.

Comment: `gdb run > file`. Then research how to output something to console and file at the same time.... Remember about buffering, specifically `stdbuf -oL` may help

Answer (score 1):

> What I need is to be able to call some commands and all of this being recorded

There are two "standard" ways to achieve this.

For manual interaction, use the [script](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) utility.

For programmatic interaction with GDB, use [DejaGNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/dejagnu/) (or expect[3](https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/expect), on which it is based). This is how GDB itself is tested; you can see many examples in GDB sources.